# JUnit order of LinkedHashMap Java 8

Tags: java, junit

i need to check full equality of two maps, including their order

```
@Test
    public void test(){
        Map<String, Integer> actual = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        actual.put("longer", 1);
        actual.put("first", 1);
        actual.put("thebiggest", 1);

        Map<String, Integer> expected = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        expected.put("thebiggest", 1);
        expected.put("longer", 1);
        expected.put("first", 1);

        System.out.println("===expected");
        expected.entrySet().stream().forEach(n->System.out.println(n.getKey()));
        System.out.println("===actual");
        actual.entrySet().stream().forEach(n->System.out.println(n.getKey()));

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
        assertTrue(expected.equals(actual));
    }
```

All tests passed, with the output in console:

```
===expected
thebiggest
longer
first
===actual
longer
first
thebiggest
```

Everywhere in the documentation it is written that LinkedHashMap is keeping order of insertion. Than why does assertion of two same but different ordered maps give true?
And what map should I take if equal order is important?

Comment: Keeping order of insertion _for iteration_***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [definition of `equals` for a `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is that they have the same entry set, regardless of order.

> Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns true if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps m1 and m2 represent the same mappings if m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet()). This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the Map interface.

If you want to assert identical iteration order, you could copy both iterations into Lists and compare the lists.

Comment: If you want to ensure same order you need a different Map type!